# WSUS updates were pushed to local host, but PC is not updated

Tags: windows-server-2012, wsus

I consider myself a self-learner in the vast ICT Forest, always eager to acquire new knowledge and skills. Today, a friend of mine has approached me with a request to push updates on a WSUS Server to all clients. As I logged into the WSUS Server, which is running on Windows Server 2012 R2, I noticed the following computer statuses:

[image: WSUS Administration Console]

- Computers with Error: 24
- Computers needing updates: 161
- Computers installed and not applicable: 3

I have not made any changes to the current settings yet. However, it is evident that most PCs are not receiving the deployed updates. In light of this situation, my question to you, the experts in Windows Server Updates, is: what should be the first thing I check to troubleshoot the issue of PCs not receiving the deployed updates?

[image: WSUS Source]

Comment: WSUS can break down. A common solution is to find the registry key for WSUS, delete it, reboot and then try again. (the regkey is automatically added when group policy is applied.

Comment: See [Troubleshoot issues with WSUS client agents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/mem/configmgr/update-management/troubleshoot-issues-with-wsus-client-agents).